# Sending Email - VB.Net - Windows Form

Tags: vb.net, email

I have tried different port numbers but I keep getting the error message and no email sent. I aim to be able to send the email successfully and the message will contain details from an appointment booked. Any help please?

```
    Dim UserName As String = "example@gmail.com"
    Dim mail As MailMessage = New MailMessage

    mail.From = New MailAddress(UserName)
    mail.To.Add(New MailAddress(txtEmailAddress.Text))
    mail.Subject = "Appointment Details"
    mail.Body = "Test message"

    mail.IsBodyHtml = True

    Dim client As SmtpClient = New SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 465)
    client.EnableSsl = True
    client.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(UserName, "***")
    Try
        client.Send(mail)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Sending email failed. Please Try again")
    End Try
```

Comment: Also, ***never** catch `System.Exception`*, catch a more specific subclass instead.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow! Please include the error message, and possibly the stack trace, in your question so that we can help you identify the problem.

Comment: When you are developing your code, do yourself a favour and find out what the error is: `MessageBox.Show("Sending email failed. Please Try again. Error message: " & ex.Message)`.

Comment: The error message was: the SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.5.1 Authentication Required.

Comment: When I used port 465. It simply says failure sending email. Error message above is for port 25

Comment: Have you tried using an ordinary email client with the same credentials? It is possible that the account has been blocked by gmail.

Comment: I don't think it has been blocked. I created this account roughly 2 days ago specifically for my project

Comment: try adding `client.UseDefaultCredentials = False` just below the client declaration. If it is set to true, the credentials of the currently logged on windows user will be sent. If it is set to false then your credentials will be sent instead

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fail Sending Email Unable To Connect the Remote Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23360415/fail-sending-email-unable-to-connect-the-remote-server)

Comment: @Drilzone this has been asked numerous times here before. Please see my link above, if that doesn't help please see the link in that post.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is add `client.UseDefaultCredentials = False`, but make sure you set it to false *before* calling `client.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(UserName, "***")`

Also, for GMail, you need to use port `587` which is the port that supports the STARTTLS extension (which is the only way that `System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient` supports SSL).

In other words, change your code to this:

```
Dim UserName As String = "example@gmail.com"
Dim mail As MailMessage = New MailMessage

mail.From = New MailAddress(UserName)
mail.To.Add(New MailAddress(txtEmailAddress.Text))
mail.Subject = "Appointment Details"
mail.Body = "Test message"

mail.IsBodyHtml = True

Dim client As SmtpClient = New SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
client.EnableSsl = True
client.UseDefaultCredentials = False
client.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(UserName, "***")
Try
    client.Send(mail)
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show("Sending email failed. Please Try again")
End Try
```

Comment: Cheers, I'll test it now. Furthermore, where it says mail.body... would I be able to place, for example txtForename.Text, and the email will send the entered data?

Comment: hmmm. I attempted to send an email and it hasn't sent yet the error message hasnt appeared. I think the issue could do with security settings.

Comment: If you didn't get an exception, then the messages was sent. It just may not have arrived yet or perhaps it got filtered into a spam folder.

Comment: @jstedfast `If you didn't get an exception, then the messages was sent`, not entirely true. It doesn't mean it was sent at all it usually means the mail server excepted it, but doesn't mean it will be sent as other issues could arise. Usually when accepted it will sit in a mail queue waiting it's turn to get sent out. The end user for example may call send and then nothing else happens. Well he misstyped the recipients address, the mail server can't send it so it pushes it aside and comes back another time, but not in all cases... The user is thought to believe it did send but it never did...

Comment: @Codexer yes, I know that. What I meant was that the message was sent to the SMTP server without error. At this point either the message will be delivered to the recipient(s) or he'll receive a bounce message(s).

Comment: In regards to exceptions, I would suggest subscribing to SendCompleted event and see if there were any errors via e.Error in SendCompleted. See a simple example here http://www.systemnetmail.com/faq/4.6.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

go to your gmail account (www.gmail.com)
login, and check that you have "enabled Pop for all mail".
you can find this under the tab "Forwarding and POP/IMAP"

Also try switching the port number to 587