# VB.NET GMAIL SMTP Server Settings

Tags: vb.net, email, smtp, gmail

I am using the Following Code for my GMAIL Server SMTP Settings, but am unable to send emails.

Can anyone help me out...

```
        Dim emailClient As New SmtpClient("mail.gmail.com")
        Dim SMTPUserInfo As New System.Net.NetworkCredential("xxxxx@gmail.com", "abc123")

        emailClient.UseDefaultCredentials = False
        emailClient.Port = 465
        emailClient.EnableSsl = True
        emailClient.Credentials = SMTPUserInfo
        emailClient.Timeout = 1000000
        emailClient.Send(mail)

        emailClient = Nothing
        SMTPUserInfo = Nothing

     Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message & " Error Mails : ", Me.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK)
    End Try
```

Comment: you are using a wrong port number for connecting to `gmail` change it as `  emailClient.Port = 587`

Comment: This has been answered before...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22814590/sending-email-from-visual-basic/22853475#22853475

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should use following settings:

```
emailClient.Host = "smtp.gmail.com"
emailClient.port = 587
emailClient.EnableSsl = True
```

Answer (score 0):

If you connect using SMTP, you can only send mail to Gmail or Google Apps users; if you connect using SSL/TLS, you can send mail to anyone. If your device or application supports SSL - connect to smtp.gmail.com on port 465. To connect with SSL, you need to provide a Google username and password for authentication.

Source: https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en